# Regex Pattern for JUnit result file name

Tags: java, regex

I have JUnit result files

1. `TEST-com.temp.junit.temptestcase.FirstTestTest.xml`
2. `TEST-com.temp.junit.temptestcase.SecondTestTest.xml`

can anyone help me form the regex pattern to match for above file names

Comment: Based on what conditions?

Comment: Can you please add negative examples too, e.g. what files you don't want to match?

Comment: Actually i found it 'TEST-[a-zA-Z\.]*\.[xml]+'. But when i am trying to use it with RegexFileFilter in java its not returning any files

Comment: In `RegexFileFilter` you need to use the right literals. I.e. `\,` becomes `\\.`. Also, I suggest to replace the `[xml]+` with `xml`. The former matches stuff like `mlx` or `xmlll`.